# convert data type and then load data into Mysql by Python

Tags: python, mysql

Besides `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, is there any other way to read a .txt file which contains three columns into Mysql? I want to read the data line by line and put them into a table in Mysql.

It is impossible to convert the datatype in the following`LOAD DATA INFILE` command, right?

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' into TABLE info (col1, col2, col3)`

My data sample is like this:

```
123456.123455   dsfd  wqoe   
123455.123237   dert  2222
098878.938475   lkjf  2346
```

So before I load the data into Mysql, I need to convert the first column from unix time into datetime since the data type of the first column in Mysql is `DATETIME`, I want to use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to solve this problem. But how can I use a python variable as the `fieldname` in `FROM_UNIXTIME(fieldname)`which is a Mysql command?

UPDATED:
This is my solution
I have three columns in the table `video`, they are `datetime, src_ip, video_id` respectively
The problem is, @unixtime variable can only save one value or? since now my first column in mysql are exactly the same, maybe it equals to the very last result..how can I solve this?

`insertQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'all-filter.txt' INTO TABLE video (@unixtime, src_ip, video_id); UPDATE video SET datetime=FROM_UNIXTIME(@unixtime)"`

Comment: You have a column in your table called "datetime"? That's an accident waiting to happen. Datetime is also an sql data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following which works:

```
create table info (s datetime not null primary key, str varchar(100), str2 varchar(100));

load data local infile '/home/maartenl/sample.txt' 
into table info (@s, str, str2) 
set s = from_unixtime(@s);
```

And that works fine with your sample set.